# Tracking Resource Change source in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I have an *xml* file in my RCP application. I am displaying it to user using `FormEditor`.

```
public class MyFormEditor extends FormEditor implements IResourceChangeListener{
    public MyFormEditor(){
        ResourcePlugin.getWorkspace.addResourceChangeListener(this);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void resourceChanged(IResourceChangeEvent event){
        int type = event.getType();

        switch(type){
            IResourceChangeEvent.PRE_DELETE:
            IResourceChangeEvent.PRE_CLOSE:
                this.close(true);
                break;
            IResourceChangeEvent.POST_CHANGE:
                System.out.println("Resource is change.");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(){
        ResourcePlugin.getWorkspace.removeResourceChangeListener(this);
        super.dispose();
    }
}
```

`IResourceChange.POST_CHANGE` event gets triggered when I save resource or I update the resource from SVN repository.

Under `IResourceChange.POST_CHANGE` how to determine resource is updated from SVN?

I tried following thing but it didn't work for me.

```
IResourceDelta delta = event.getDelta;
int flags = delta.getFlags();
boolean sync = (flags & IResourceDelta.SYNC) != 0;
if(sync){
    System.out.println("Resource updated from server.");
}
```

Do let me know if you need any other info.

Comment: what did not work in your proposed solution? was IResourceDelta.SYNC  not set?

Comment: int flags = delta.getFlags(); return 0 in two conditions. 1st when I save the file 2nd when I update it from server. In both case delta.getFlags() shown no change.